# Stanford Eclipse not building applications properly

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

Trying to figure out what's going wrong here so I can actually use the graphics library.

My Code Looks like:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        add(new GLabel("hello world", 100, 75));
    }
}
```

You'd think not much can go wrong with code this simple but after running, I get this: no errors. Any ideas? Also anyone knows why eclipse is so buggy? (I normally write code for the java console and even then it seems to completely crash randomly during builds.)

[image: pyramid]

Comment: Just a thought: (where) do you call run()?

Comment: Are you able to post some more of your code to assess or is this the whole program?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `GraphicsProgram` class or with `acm`, but have you tried putting `add(new GLabel("hello world", 100, 75))` within a constructor of your `Pyramid` class rather than in the run() method? (I might be completely wrong here, have never worked with the acm.graphics package.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug with stanfords version of eclipse. When you make any kind of code change, you have to refresh the project manually before running or building the project otherwise all changes won't be current since the build only works off the last refresh of the project. To do this you have to right click the project on the penumbra tab and click refresh. The F5 shortcut won't work out of box.

The reason the F5 refresh button won't work out of box is because its set to two functions by default. Refresh when editing and Step Into when Debugging. For whatever reason even if there is no debug window open, Step Into has higher priority then refresh so it won't work. To fix this you need to go into Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys find Step Into and remap it or delete the mapping if you don't plan on using the debugger. Click Apply afterwards. Then refresh will work properly.